# jQuery - Updating clicked image in jQuery.ajax().done()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few images, like

```
<img src="unstarred.png" class="unstarred-button" id="unstarred-1" />
<img src="unstarred.png" class="unstarred-button" id="unstarred-2" />
<img src="unstarred.png" class="unstarred-button" id="unstarred-3" />
<img src="unstarred.png" class="unstarred-button" id="unstarred-4" />
```

Then I bind this function:

```
$('.unstarred-button').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^unstarred-/, '');
    url = '/star.php?id=' + id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  url
    }).done(function() {
        // What should be put here?
    });
});
```

Now I don't know how to go forward. I want to change the `src` attribute of the clicked image in the `done()` call, but $(this) doesn't return the image clicked for sure, as `$(this).attr('id')` is `undefined` according to `alert()`.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `this` within the context of `done` doesn't refer to `img`. You need to save the context in the `click` event handler:

```
$('.unstarred-button').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    id = self.attr('id').replace(/^unstarred-/, '');
    url = '/star.php?id=' + id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  url
    }).done(function() {
        self.attr('src', 'something.jpg');
    });
});
```

Also, you don't need jQuery to change the `src` or an `id` of a DOM element, you can change the attribute directly, i.e., `this.src = 'something.jpg` or `this.id = 'new_id'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.unstarred-button').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    var id = this.id.replace(/^unstarred-/, '');
    var url = '/star.php?id=' + id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  url
    }).done(function() {
        that.src = 'some/new/src.jpg';
    });
});
```